# After matching a line, how do I read some more lines and record values, then start over? Python

Tags: python, loops, text-files, readline, doc

I am wondering how to search a text document for the word POLYLINE, and then once I find it, how to keep searching the text document for more attributes for POLYLINE, like x coordinates and y coordinates, and then find the next POLYLINE and do it again.

I have a text file that looks like this:

1. POLYLINE
2. blah
3. X coord
4. fifty
5. Y coord
6. sixty three
7. blah
8. blah
9. X coord
10. ninety
11. Y coord
12. six
13. POLYLINE
14. And so on...

All my code does so far is find the word POLYLINE, I am stuck trying to collect the attributes of POLYLINE.
Here is my code so far:

```
import re

fileName = open("textdoc.txt, "r")



for line in fileName:
    if re.match("POLYLINE", line):
        print line



fileName.close()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for line in fileName:
    if re.match("POLYLINE", line):
        for line in filename:
            if re.match(xcoord,line):
                dostuff()
            if re.match(ycoord,line):
                dostuff()
```

As to how you could actually find the coordinates, it's hard for us to do anything with what you've provided. If there is no pattern as to what line the coordinates will appear in or if there are other numbers that are not your coordinates, and those numbers don't have some sort of identification as such, then there's not much you can do. Basically, find whatever it is that allows you to differentiate the coordinates from anything else, and then just search for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure is consistent you could collect the attributes like below.

```
#store polylines in a list for future use
polylines=[]

dataFile = open('textdoc.txt')

#collect the attributes in dictionaries
attrs={}

#because it appears you need to look one line ahead to get the coordinates
# it would be easiest to read all lines into a list

datalines = dataFile.readlines()
for idx, line in enumerate(datalines):
    #handle polyline flags by storing the previous attributes
    if 'POLYLINE' in line:
        #attrs will evaluate to True if its not empty
        if attrs:
            #append the old polyline attributes and start a new one
            polylines.append(attrs)
            attrs = {}

        continue

    #collect the attributes from the line following the coord flag
    # of course this breaks real fast if the file structure changes
    if 'xcoord' in line:
        #grab the coordinate from the following line
        attrs['xcoord'] = datalines[idx + 1].strip()
        continue

    if 'ycoord' in line:
        attrs['ycoord'] = datalines[idx + 1].strip()
        continue
```